# BINARY data not inserting into mysql extracted from a BINARY(20) column?

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I have some data that I am trying to insert into a table that is retrieved from another table in mysql which has the data type `BINARY(20)`.

The data extracted is in the variable `$binary['hash'];`

**/l÷ˆ8Ô]¿\µK<þeû**

When I try to insert into another table using `PDO` like below, (the column hash is `BINARY(20)` also)

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (hash) VALUES (?)");
$q -> execute(array($binary['hash']));
```

I get an error like such,

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('\0/l÷ˆ8Ô]¿\µK<þeû')' at line 1'**

I notice that the value of `$binary['hash']` is different and it is not inserting!

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper sql statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO table (hash) VALUES (?)
```

Without the first `VALUES` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You have `values` twice in your SQL statement and that's the error

INSERT INTO table **VALUES (hash) VALUES (?)**

it shouold be

```
INSERT INTO table (hash) VALUES (?)
```